# AWS Mongo QuickStart never completes

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, templates, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

**Problem**

I am trying to complete the [MongoDB on AWS quickstart](https://s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-reference/mongodb/latest/doc/MongoDB_on_the_AWS_Cloud.pdf) to create a simple MongoDB cluster. Unfortunately it never completes the rollout, cancelling after one last installation part (PrimaryReplicaNodeXYWaitForNodeInstallGP2) has not been completed within an hour.

**Background**

My Settings were the following:

```
AvailabilityZone0   eu-central-1a
AvailabilityZone1   eu-central-1b
AvailabilityZone2   eu-central-1b
BuildBucket quickstart-reference/mongodb/latest
ClusterReplicaSetCount  0
ClusterShardCount   1
ConfigServerInstanceType    t2.micro
Iops    100
KeyName my_definitely_working_keypair
MongoDBVersion  3.2
NATInstanceType t2.small
NodeInstanceType    m3.medium
PrimaryReplicaSubnet    10.0.2.0/24
PublicSubnet    10.0.1.0/24
RemoteAccessCIDR    XXX.XXX.0.0/16
SecondaryReplicaSubnet0 10.0.3.0/24
SecondaryReplicaSubnet1 10.0.4.0/24
ShardsPerNode   0
VolumeSize  40
VolumeType  gp2
VPCCIDR 10.0.0.0/16
```

Which caused a rollback in the [same behaviour, as named in the AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=717827):

> In "Ressources", all but one subtask never gets completed and stays on
>   forever as "PrimaryReplicaNode0WaitForNodeInstallGP2 -
>   PrimaryReplicaNode0WaitForNodeInstallWaitHandle - Created in Progress
>   - Ressource creation initiated"

So, I was further researching on the issue. The post referred [to another forum thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=230785), where users with the problem should try to delete their DynamoDB entries and set ClusterReplicaSetCount to 3.

Problem here: In DynamoDB there are no entries and changing ClusterReplicaSetCount to 3 also causes a rollback with a similar error:

> ConfigServer2WaitForNodeInstall   WaitCondition timed out. Received 0
>   conditions when expecting 1

and later

> MONGODBSTACK1 The following resource(s) failed to create:
>   [ConfigServer1WaitForNodeInstall,
>   PrimaryReplicaNode00WaitForNodeInstallGP2,
>   ConfigServer0WaitForNodeInstall,
>   SecondaryReplicaNode00WaitForNodeInstallGP2,
>   SecondaryReplicaNode01WaitForNodeInstallGP2,
>   ConfigServer2WaitForNodeInstall].

**Summary**

In both cases there is a fail on **PrimaryReplicaNodeXYWaitForNodeInstallGP2** (where XY is the number of the node) while all other parts of the installation completed successfully. I am totally in the dark.

Anyone got around this? The quick start is from 2016 and I think there must be people, who have successfully created this mongo stack!?

Comment: Who ever voted for closing this: can you please refer to a solution to this issue? Has no one here ever set up a mongo db on AWS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days and days of hard struggle and no solution there was [an update](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/mongodb/revisions.html) (since over a year, feels as if my prayers were heard) on the manual and the template:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/mongodb/welcome.html

So this also comes with a completely revised infrastructure and a more sophisticated setup form, changes are described as:

> Upgraded MongoDB to version 3.4; removed sharding configuration;
>   updated security groups and added database security; updated
>   parameters

Following the tutorial is quite similar to the former versions, so no struggle here.

Everything went out fine and I got my stack completed now consisting of a

mongoDB
mongoDB Replica
bastion stack
vpc stack

So this part is basically done. If something else comes up, I will open a new question for that.

Comment: Hi Jankapunkt, the MongoDB on AWS quickstart works the first time in an existing VPC. I had to delete and recreate the stack and for some reason it gets stuck at all the WaitConditionHandles (PrimaryReplicaNode0WaitForNodeInstall, SecondaryReplicaNode0WaitForNodeInstall, SecondaryReplicaNode1WaitForNodeInstall). Did you face this issue?

Comment: @naveenkumarbv I'm presently experiencing the same issue, where recreating a stack with the same name after everything is torn down just pauses at the WaitConditions. Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this after tearing down a dev cluster and attempting to stand up a new one with the same name.

The torn down cluster orphaned a dynamodb table with the name the new stack was trying to publish the worker nodes status onto. I deleted this dynamo table manually and reattempted to spin up the stack with the same name a third time and had success.